# Will My DLCs Be Kept On A PS3 Without An Account?

Tags: ps3, psn, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

My friend doesn't have a PSN account and doesn't have any DLCs for a game that we play. I have the DLCs on *my* Ps3 (I have a PSN account) and I was going to sign in on my account on *his* Ps3 so we could play on the DLCs together at his house. But I was wondering if my DLCs will be kept on his Ps3 even if I signed out. Thanks in advance for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you sign-in to your PSN account on your friend's PS3 and install DLC from your account, it will stay on his PS3. But, you won't be able to do this again until 90 days passed. Also, he doesn't have to be on your PSN to use the DLC.